# How to change the order of datalist images from left to right or right to left?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist

I have a datalist and 2 button life right which is outside of datalist

datalist:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlst" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                                RepeatColumns="5" CellSpacing="8">
         <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:ImageButton ID="Image" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#"~/Controls/Showimg.ashx?FileName=" +DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FilePath") %>'  OnCommand="ImageSelect_Command" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id").ToString() +";"+Eval("FilePath")+";"+Eval("Index")+";"+Eval("FileName") %>' /><br />
                  <asp:Label ID="nlbl" runat="server" Text="Figure"></asp:Label><%# dlst.Items.Count + 1%>
            </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:DataList>
```

buttons:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnleft" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/arrowLBlue.png"
                                ToolTip="Move Item Left"  OnClick="btnleft_Click" />
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnright" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/arrowRBlue.png"
                                ToolTip="Move Item Right"  />
```

I am uploading and binding the images its working fine, now I want to move a selected image from left to right or right to left on my button click, suppose i have image a1, a2, a3, a4, a5 and i clicked on btnmoveright after selecting the image a2 then the image order should be a1,a3,a2,a4,a5 now if again i clicked on btnmoveright after selecting the image a2 then order should be a1,a3,a4,a2,a5 like this I want to move the image.
How to do that? Please someone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the datasource for your datalist is a collection of strings representing the filepaths.  If so, just swap the selected item with the one to the left or the right and rebind.

```
Public Sub Swap(ByVal obj1 As Object, ByVal obj2 As Object)
   Dim temp As Object = obj1
   obj1 = obj2
   obj2 = temp
End Sub
```

You can store the collection in the viewstate or in a session object to reinstantiate it easily after postback without requerying the original source.

Comment: but how to get the selected index of next item and previous item?